# CMake GoogleTests can't find header file imported in my test file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

We (three students) are very new to CMake. For a university project we have to include GoogleTest into our codebase, and we are having a lot of trouble with it.

We have a `gtest_ours.cmake` file:

```
project("googletests")

enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SRC
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        # header don't need to be included but this might be necessary for some IDEs
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        EXCLUDE
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MolSim.cpp"
        )

add_subdirectory(googletest)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(ParticleContainerTest ${sources} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/ParticleContainerTest.cpp )
target_link_libraries(ParticleContainerTest ${MY_SRC} gtest gtest_main gmock gmock_main)

gtest_discover_tests(ParticleContainerTest)

set_tests_properties(${noArgsTests}   PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 10)
set_tests_properties(${withArgsTests} PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 20)
```

and from the `CMakeLists.txt` file, we just call:

```
include(gtest_ours)
```

Our folder structure is:

```
main
- src
- test
- CMakeLists.txt
- others
```

Please help, we get the following error:

```
/home/lunaticcoding/psemoldyn_groupc/MolSim-master/test/ParticleContainerTest.cpp:9:10: fatal error: ../src/ParticleContainer.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../src/ParticleContainer.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/ParticleContainerTest.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ParticleContainerTest.dir/test/ParticleContainerTest.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ParticleContainerTest.dir/test/ParticleContainerTest.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:144: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ParticleContainerTest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ParticleContainerTest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: If you add `"."` to `include_directories` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the `gtest_ours.cmake` file. Your error is raised because you haven't defined the include directories for your `ParticleContainerTest` target to include `ParticleContainer.h`. You've only added `gtest_SOURCE_DIR` directories as include directories. To correct this, consider adding this line after `add_executable()`:

```
target_include_directories(ParticleContainerTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

This way, the `src` directory will be an include directory, so you can modify `test/ParticleContainerTest.cpp` to have a more reasonable `#include`:

```
#include "ParticleContainer.h"
```

---

Also, I'm not sure where you intend to use the `${MY_SRC}` source files, but you don't want to include this in the `target_link_libraries()` call. This call should only include pre-defined *targets*, *library* names, or linking options as arguments; do not add a list of source files to this call. I'm also not sure where you defined the `${sources}` argument in the `add_executable()` call, but perhaps, you meant to put `${MY_SRC}` there instead.

---

Finally, the `EXCLUDE` qualifier does not work with the `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` signature. However, you can remove a *specific* file from the list **afterward**, using  [`list(REMOVE_ITEM ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#remove-item):

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        # header don't need to be included but this might be necessary for some IDEs
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
)
list(REMOVE_ITEM MY_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MolSim.cpp)
```

Comment: How do I exclude a file.cpp containing a main function inside the src directory
in here :

file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SRC
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        # header don't need to be included but this might be necessary for some IDEs
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        EXCLUDE
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MolSim.cpp"
        )

Comment: I am including the files by hand (one by one) for now and it is working (if you happen to know how to answer the comment above it would be amazing)

but since it's working -> I LOVE YOU, MATE :DDDD THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH

Comment: @MarcoPapula Including the files one-by-one is the preferred method; there are often unintended consequences (as warned in the CMake documentation for `file(GLOB ... )` itself). However, I expanded my answer to show how you can exclude one file from the list using `GLOB`. Glad it's working!